# Could not find SDK folder in Android Eclipse

Tags: android

I want to install Android SDK for Mac. I have download the sdk ADT Bundle for mac and done another process then rename the "Android Developer" and move into "Application".

But when I click on the Eclipse for open I got the pop up message:

> could not find SDK folder ' User/developer/downloads/android-sdk-macosx/'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your SDK location like following screenshot. no different on Mac:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

you renamed the unzipped directory? don't do this. Or it may happen if you changed the location of unzipped directory.

Solution (If you don't want to unzip ADT bundle again)

In Eclipse:- goto Window->Preferences->Android and you will see "SDK Location". Browse to your SDK location and say OK.

Answer (score 1):

Running Win 8.1 x64 here, and there is a really simple solution, unzip the adt bundle again.

I unzipped mine into the Downloads folder here:

C:\Users(myusername)\Downloads\adt-bundle-(blah-blah)\adt-bundle-(blah-blah)

So I cut (CTRL-X) the second "adt-bundle-(blah-blah)" and moved to C:\Program Files\adt-bundle-(blah-blah)

Then I just started the eclipse from within that adt-bundle folder location and it fixed up the settings location.

Now when I start my "other" eclipse (kepler) installation, it picks up the correct location as well.